# Why should i use get instead of post?

Tags: c#, web-services, http-post, http-get

I have a web service which is developed in mvc c#, the purpose of the service is to retrieve and insert data to sql. All methods are using http attributes, so my question is, if all methods are using [HttpPost] and is working fine, when do i should use [HttpGet].

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetVehiculos")]
    public HttpResponseMessage WSGetVehiculos()
    {
        VehiculosDAO vehiculosDAO = new VehiculosDAO();
        List<Vehiculo> lstVehiculo = new List<Vehiculo>();
        string codError = "0";
        string mensaje = "";
        try
        {
            lstVehiculo = vehiculosDAO.GetVehiculos();
            
            mensaje = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            codError ="1";
            Log.WriteToFileLogGeneral(ex.Message);

        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Msg = mensaje, CodError = 
        codError,Data= lstVehiculo } );
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should one use GET instead of POST in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226732/when-should-one-use-get-instead-of-post-in-a-web-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET is used for viewing something, without changing it, while POST is used for changing something. For example, a search page should use GET to get data while a form that changes your password should use POST. Essentially GET is used to retrieve remote data, and POST is used to insert/update remote data.

Comment: It's all quite arbitrary though; no one will put a gun to your head and say "use POST or die!"

Comment: sure, but there are some accepted principles and concepts which should follow to have a readable code and intuitive system